# Javascript popup Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

Can I, and some references in case, make a google chrome extension that is basically a javascript popup. What I'm doing, is a share popup, and I currently have it saved as a bookmark like this:

```
javascript:window.open ('http://www.example.com/share.php?link='+(location.href), 'newwindow', config='height=200,width=520, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, directories=no, status=no')
```

but I would love to make it into a small extension that at least I could use.

Is this possible, and if yes, please add some references.

Comment: Wouldn't it work better as a Bookmarklet?

Comment: A window pop-up, or just an external instance? See [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html), [`chrome.windows`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html) and [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) (for the last two, specifically the `create` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this page, http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Im sure if making it a google chrome extension is the best plan but it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's unnecessary and stuff, it's just an example so that I know if I can use Javascript this way in extensions. Thank you.